# Place shape under timeseries plot

Tags: r, time-series

I have a relatively simple plot with two shapes and labels:

```
plot.ts(timeseries, xlab = "Week - Beginning in 2012", ylab = "Interest - 
Percentage of Max", 
lwd = 2, ylim = c(0, 120), xlim = c(0,250))
text(c(210, 115), c(105, 55), labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2"))
rect(200, 0, 220, 100, col = "green", density = 20)
rect(100, 0, 130, 50, col = "green", density = 20)
```

I have searched for a way to get the boxes under the time series plot line, but I've had no luck with both abline and panel.first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make your examples reproducible, particularly in the R tag. So could you please use some builtin data or otherwise reproducible strategy with this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You mean by attaching a dataset?

Comment: You can use a built-in data set (see `data()` for options) or create the dataset within your code. For instance `z <- ts(matrix(rt(200 * 8, df = 3), 200, 1),
        start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to look at your x- and y- axes and choose good corresponding coordinates for the text labels and edges of the boxes. You'll get it wrong at first but then you can play with it until it's perfect.

Make sure you have a good understanding of which parameter in `text` and `rect` corresponds to which coordinate. See `?text` and `?rect` for the legend.

```
z <- ts(matrix(rt(200 * 8, df = 3), 200, 1),
        start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)

plot.ts(z, xlab = "Week - Beginning in 2012", ylab = "Interest - 
Percentage of Max")

text(c(1965, 1970), c(-5, -5), labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2"))
rect(1963, -6, 1967, -4, col = "green", density = 20)
rect(1968, -6, 1972, -4, col = "green", density = 20)
```

[image]

Based on the comment you just left that says

> I'm using the boxes will serve as a way to highlight areas of the plot
>   - so I need the plot line to show on top of the boxes, which will be colored in.

I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
plot.ts(z, xlab = "Week - Beginning in 2012", ylab = "Interest - 
Percentage of Max")

text(c(1965, 1970), c(-5, -5), labels = c("Label 1", "Label 2"))
rect(1963, -1, 1967, 1, col = "green", density = 20)
rect(1968, -1, 1972, 1, col = "green", density = 20)
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based on a comment you just left that says

> what I need is that line to be in front of the green box, as opposed
>   to behind it.

What you're going to want is to re-plot the line with `lines` after adding the rectangles like this:

```
plot.ts(z, xlab = "Week - Beginning in 2012", ylab = "Interest - 
Percentage of Max")

i <- .25*(0:20)
rect(1963+i, -6+i, 1967+i, -4+i, col = rainbow(11, start = 0.7, end = 0.1))
lines(z)

text(c(1970, 1975), c(-5, -5), labels = c("Boom", "How about that?"), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I plotted this answer and the labels and boxes are still on top of the data - or were you demonstrating a reproducible example?

Comment: In the actual data I'm using the boxes will serve as a way to highlight areas of the plot - so I need the plot line to show on top of the boxes, which will be colored in.

Comment: @Josh.D I'm not clear on what you're asking for that's not here. It might be easier if you provide the example data and then use a paint program to show what you're wanting.

Comment: The graph you kindly produced above shows the green lines in the box (containing "Label 2") as in front of the time series plot data - what I need is that line to be in **front** of the green box, as opposed to behind it. @Hack-R

Comment: If instead of the original rect, we change it to:
    rect(1963, -1, 1967, 1, col = "green")
It may be easier to see what I'm talking about.  In this case the green box is covering the plot, I need the plot line on top of the box.

Comment: @Josh.D Got it no problem. I was just making a new answer. I'm about to update it again.

Comment: THANK YOU so much.  I really appreciate your time for putting up with my banter.

Comment: @Josh.D No problem, happy to help. If you really want to thank me you'll click that little green checkmark by the answer :)